# How to clear value in people picker using js

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an item in SharePoint List with type data people picker.

Approver 1 edits an item ,puts Assign To on people picker, and then click save button. 
Next Approver 2 edits the same item and then put Assign To on people picker, can previous value in people picker be erased?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[$('[Title*="Test"]')[0].id];
    if (peoplePicker.TotalUserCount > 0) {
        peoplePicker.DeleteProcessedUser();
    }
});
```